# PHP : Carousel Bootstrap CSS

Tags: php, javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to use Bootstrap CSS Carousel. The left and right arrows are not working and the slides are not switching automatically... I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code :

index.php

```
<?php
  include("header.php");
?>
  <body>

  <?php
    include("menu.php");
    include("carousel.php");
  ?>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2013 Company</p>
  </footer>

  <?php
    include("script.php");
  ?>
      <script>
        !function ($) {
          $(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel()
          })
        }(window.jQuery)
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

carousel.php

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>ITEM 1</h1>
          <p class="lead">Description 1.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>ITEM 2</h1>
          <p class="lead">Description 2.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>ITEM 3</h1>
          <p class="lead">Description 3.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel NAV -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

script.php (*edited)

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/holder/holder.js"></script>
```

PS : I cannot program in JS neither in JQuery.

Comment: Have you used firebug to diagnose any bugs/errors with the bootstrap you have downloaded? verified that they all exist?

Comment: +1 Also, you are including jQuery twice? Once local and once from googleapis.com?

Comment: is your bootstrap.min.js customised or it is a complete js file? Because if you refer the same thing twice it causes problems, so if your bootstrap.min.js is not customized refmove reference of other files like bootstrap-carousel.js,bootstrap-collapse.js etc

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything Since my bootstrap.min.js is not customized, I removed the other files as you said. Now, I have the 3 following scripts : <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/holder/holder.js"></script>
But it is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
</script>
```

Running this script at the beginning of the page instead of the end makes it working. In the script.php file I run the following scripts :

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```